# Java suppress all console output

Tags: java, console

I have a unit test which causes another software component to wildly print stacktraces.
I would like to suppress this output because it is expected.

My problem now is: even if I redirect System.out and System.err, I still get these stacktraces in the console which is confusing when analysing test logs.

What am I missing? Is there yet another way to print to the console?

Comment: How is the other software component included in your project? Also, are the stack traces written to the log (as should be) or directly to stout/stderr? In the first case you could simply configure the logger accordingly.

Comment: Is your software maybe using log4j, or a similar logging framework? If so, have a look at the configurable 'log appenders'.

Comment: The other component is included via osgi/equinox. It does indeed use log4j. I will have a look at that.